# Xcode failed to update properly

Tags: xcode, build

ALL,

For some unknown reason my Xcode failed to update the command after I changed the settings.

This is the command it is running:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/igorkorot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/igorkorot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wunguarded-availability -fsanitize=address -D_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ASAN -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize=enum,return,float-divide-by-zero,function,vptr -index-store-path /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates.noindex/libpropertieshandlers.build/Debug/libpropertieshandlers.build/libpropertieshandlers-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates.noindex/libpropertieshandlers.build/Debug/libpropertieshandlers.build/libpropertieshandlers-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates.noindex/libpropertieshandlers.build/Debug/libpropertieshandlers.build/libpropertieshandlers-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates.noindex/libpropertieshandlers.build/Debug/libpropertieshandlers.build/libpropertieshandlers-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Users/igorkorot/wxWidgets/buildC11/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2 -I/Users/igorkorot/wxWidgets/include -I../dbinterface -I../libpropertypages -I../libshapeframework -I../libfieldswindow -I../libdbwindow -I/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates.noindex/libpropertieshandlers.build/Debug/libpropertieshandlers.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates.noindex/libpropertieshandlers.build/Debug/libpropertieshandlers.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates.noindex/libpropertieshandlers.build/Debug/libpropertieshandlers.build/Objects-normal-asan-ubsan/x86_64/propertieshandler.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates.noindex/libpropertieshandlers.build/Debug/libpropertieshandlers.build/Objects-normal-asan-ubsan/x86_64/propertieshandler.dia -c /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/libpropertieshandlers/propertieshandler.cpp -o /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates.noindex/libpropertieshandlers.build/Debug/libpropertieshandlers.build/Objects-normal-asan-ubsan/x86_64/propertieshandler.o
```

This is the directory and the files I need to include:

```
Igors-MacBook-Air:libhelpers igorkorot$ pwd
/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/libhelpers
Igors-MacBook-Air:libhelpers igorkorot$ ls -la
total 408
drwxr-xr-x  24 igorkorot  staff    768 Dec 24 19:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  53 igorkorot  staff   1696 Dec 11 21:25 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 igorkorot  staff   6148 Dec 23 10:38 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff    324 Dec 11 21:25 Makefile.am
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff   2361 Dec 23 10:36 colorcombobox.cpp
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff   1131 Dec 23 10:36 colorcombobox.h
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff    141 Dec 17 13:08 dbloader10.vcxproj.user
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff   1038 Dec 11 21:25 helpers.filters
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff     30 Dec 11 21:25 helpers.opensdf
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff    141 Dec 11 21:25 helpers.user
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff  23911 Dec 11 21:25 helpers.vcproj
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff  36666 Dec 24 19:33 helpers.vcxproj
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff    871 Dec 23 10:36 helpers.vcxproj.filters
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff    141 Dec 11 21:25 helpers.vcxproj.user
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff   1038 Dec 11 21:25 helpers10.filters
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff     30 Dec 11 21:25 helpers10.opensdf
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff    141 Dec 11 21:25 helpers10.user
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff  23911 Dec 11 21:25 helpers10.vcproj
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff  35944 Dec 11 21:25 helpers10.vcxproj
drwxr-xr-x@  4 igorkorot  staff    128 Dec 23 10:38 libhelpers.xcodeproj
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff  10381 Dec 17 13:08 my_dll.cpp
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff    841 Dec 17 13:08 my_dll.h
-rw-r--r--   1 igorkorot  staff   4831 Dec 17 13:08 typecombobox.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 igorkorot  staff    382 Dec 17 13:11 typecombobox.h
Igors-MacBook-Air:libhelpers igorkorot$
```

And this is the screenshot of what the Xcode project settings lok like:

[image]

The error I am getting is:

```
/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/libpropertieshandlers/propertieshandler.cpp:34:10: fatal error: 'colorcombobox.h' file not found
#include "colorcombobox.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Can someone shed some lights of what is going on here?

The file is definitely there and according to the Xcode project settings should be found, but its not.

TIA!!!

EDIT:

What's weird is that if I get the command to compile from the Xcode, add the proper `-I` to it and run it in the Terminal, it works!! No error is produced.